# Replace AND with NOT function in formula

Tags: excel-formula

My Table looks like :

[Table.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbk29y59ngq3w32/book2.xlsx?dl=0)
* The table needs to be downloaded to get formula works on.

On column "W" I have the following formula :

```
=IF(AND(J19="HLD";Q19="");"HLD";"")
```

Which will add value "HLD" in column W if HLD value exist in column J and Column Q is empty.

My problem with this formula is that I have more then one value ( CNA , CFF , HLD ) which needs to be considered as HLD in column W .

When I try to :

```
=IF(AND(J19="HLD , CNA , CFF";Q19="");"HLD";"")
```

The formula doesn't work .

Interesting here is that I need all values except STD to be valued as HLD in column W and I was thinking for something like :

```
=IF(NOT(J19="STD";Q19="");"HLD";"")
```

But looks like doesn't work.

Other problem which I'm facing in this table is that.

In column X I have the following formula :

```
=IF(C19="";"";IF(AND(K19="Putaway";MID(J19;1;3)="CFF");0;NUMBERVALUE(C19)))
```

Which will do the following :

If in column K we have value Putaway and if column J have value CFF will be counted as 0

For the rest of values in K and J columns the formula will copy the value from column C .

My problem with here is that I have more then one value in column J which needs to be counted as 0 . I want all values CNA , CFF , HLD to be counted as 0 or other way around ... all except HLD to be counted as 0 .

Thanks for support

Comment: Please prepare a truth table of what you try to do.

Comment: Truth table was provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula in Cell `W2` and drag it down.

```
=IF(AND(J2<>"STD";Q2="");J2;"")
```

> `<>` will work as the "NOT" you were after. **NOT** function in excel is not working in the way you want. The above formula will return the value from Column J as long as the value in column J is not `STP` AND column Q is blank `""`.

Formula in Cell `X2` and drag it down.

```
=IF(C2="";"";IF(AND(K2="Putaway";J2<>"STD");0;NUMBERVALUE(C2)))
```

> If you understand the use of `<>' in the last formula, then there is no need to explain further for this one.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: @ApAMiX no worries, if you want to use NOT, you can try `AND(NOT(J2="STP");Q2="")` in the first formula, but I think `<>` is simpler.